# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined - Trying to toggle a class in JS

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

I am simply trying to toggle a class on and off with a click for a todo list app I am creating with vanilla JS only (no jQuery).  What am I missing or doing wrong? Here is the code I have now

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<h1> Todo List </h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="New todo">
<ul>
<li> item 1</li>
<li> item 2 </li>
<li> item 3 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1")
var li = document.getElementByTagName("li")

for ( var i = 0 ; i < li.length ; i++){
    li[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    li[i].classList.toggle("done");
    })
}
```

When I click on an item in the list, it gives me this error in the console - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

1. Instead of `getElementByTagName`, it should be `getElementsByTagName`:

   ```
   li = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
   ```
2. Inside the event handler definied on the `li` elements, you could refer to the `li` elements using `this` instead of `li[i]`.

   Basically the problem is the `i` is incremented by your `for` loop, and when the click handler actually executes the value of `i` is 3. So referring to `li[i]` is an error because there are only three `li` elements (so up to `li[2]`).

Here's the updated snippet:

```js
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1")
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li")

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
  })
}
```

```css
.done {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1> Todo List </h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="New todo">
  <ul>
    <li> item 1</li>
    <li> item 2 </li>
    <li> item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Responding to ikrabbe in comments, you could create the indexing variable `i` in local scope using `let` keyword: `let i = 0`. But note that it won't work with older browsers.

```js
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1")
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li")

for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    li[i].classList.toggle("done");
  })
}
```

```css
.done {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1> Todo List </h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="New todo">
  <ul>
    <li> item 1</li>
    <li> item 2 </li>
    <li> item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain why `li[i]` is a problem here.

Comment: another part to answer this special question is, how to get parameters like `i` into the handler function, because that's why the error happened.

Comment: @ikrabbe Frankly I chose to suggest using `this` because it is generally a good choice for such cases and doesn't run into bugs. But yes, there are a couple of ways in which `li[i]` could be used. But it is often difficult to explore all available options in the scope of one answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `scope/value of i` was the problem. When clicking on the element the value of `i` is incremented to 3(in this case) because of `i++`.
You can use `let` instead of `var`

```js
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1")
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li")

for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // console.log(i) // will log i =3 if let is replaced by var
    li[i].classList.toggle("done");
  })
  
}
```

```css
.done{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1> Todo List </h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="New todo">
  <ul>
    <li> item 1</li>
    <li> item 2 </li>
    <li> item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting. I haven't learned about let yet. why does let increment it to 3?